# Cannot login with Microsoft Edge (Windows 10 browser)

Tags: bug, login, microsoft-edge

Stack Overflow does not log me in automatically when using Microsoft Edge. Also clicking on "login" does some flickering and returns to the start page. I'm logging in with StackExchange Open ID.

However, StackExchange does log me in automatically as do all my other Stack Exchange sites (Code Review, Programmers, Database Administrators, Meta Stack Exchange). But navigating to Stack Overflow does not keep me logged in.

Note that my login works with Firefox.

After I open the browser Developer Tools (F12), the tools window closes when I try to navigate to the login page. Very strange. It stays open when I navigate to other places.

What is different with the Stack Overflow login?
How can I fix this?

Comment: No repro.  How are you logging in? Username/password?  Or using g+?  You're not using facebook, are you?

Comment: I'm logging in with Stackexchange Open ID.

Comment: Just switched to Win10 today and having the same issue. After clicking the login button Edge returns to the previous page but I am still not logged in. Trying to go again to the login page fails with a flicker and Leaves you to the same initial page. Removing the cached passwords and other elements through Edge Settings allows the login page to show again but then the cycle repeats. Trying to login to another site works without problems and the Stackexchange top bar menu shows the correct reputation for StackOverflow.

Comment: Found a way to login with Edge. Using the direct link https://stackoverflow.com/users/login  (without any querystring appended) tells me that I am already logged in. Now switching back to Stackoverflow works and keeps my login information

Comment: This works for me too. If you include it as answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Still banging my head around this problem. The weird thing is that I have no problem at all with my Home devices (a PC, a notebook and a Surface tablet) but the work PC refuses to remember my credentials. The only thing different that I have noticed is that all my personal devices use the Microsoft account to login while the work PC uses a local account not connected to my Microsoft Account

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Do you still have this problem? Accidentaly today in a chat in the SOCVR I encountered a problem with a script that refuted to do its work when executed from Edge. The author of the script told me that the script problem is connected to Trusted Zone implementation and to the fact that Edge doesn't pass the authentication cookies to the chat page. I wonder if adding the stackoverlow.com domain to the Trusted Zone changes something. I cannot test my old work pc because I don't work anymore there. Trusted Zone cannot be changed by Edge options but only from Control Panel

Comment: I have a completely new installation, where the problem does not occur anymore. But your suggestion can certainly help others having this problem.

Comment: @TinyGiant: No, this one was asked first (Sep '15). The other was asked Sep '16 and has no answer.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes It doesn't matter which one was asked first. Neither has an actual answer as the bug has not been solved. All of the information spread about this Q&A have been succinctly summarized in the linked Q&A. The date the question was asked has no bearing on which should be marked as a duplicate of which. We don't need two questions for the same problem, and the other one has all the same information as this one, but it doesn't have nearly as much noise, so I picked that one as the target.

Comment: The mentioned duplicate doesn't have any answer! Does it make sense to redirect to a question having no answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just switched to Win10 today and having the same issue.
After clicking the login button and writing the correct username and password,  Edge returns to the main page but doesn't show the link to my user page and keeps showing the login/signup buttons. Pressing again the login button fails with a flicker and leaves you to the same initial page.

Going to Edge Settings and removing everything from the previous navigation (including cached passwords and other elements) allows the login page to show again but then the cycle repeats.
Trying to login to another stackexchange site works without problems and the Stackexchange top bar menu shows the correct reputation also for StackOverflow.

Finally I have found a half workaround.

Instead of pressing the login button use the direct link to [stackoverflow.com/users/login](https://stackoverflow.com/users/login) (without any querystring appended). The page, surprisingly, tells you that you are already logged in. Now clicking the StackOverflow button/banner on the top left of the page transfers to the main stackoverflow page and you could see the link to your user page with the count of badges and reps (And if you are subscribed to the new-nav beta test you have your tabs correctly displayed).

I have said that this is an half workaround because I have not found a way to to defeat the problem using this system if you need to login to meta.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Another thing to check is if Edge accepts cookies in the settings.  If no cookies are accepted then SO doesn't remember you logged in.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and turned off flash in the advanced settings and the logon process works as I would expect.  In fact, many other websites behave better since turning off flash.