# Login with MS Edge does not work

Tags: bug, login, microsoft-edge

Although the question I have is exactly the same as [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/306825), none of the mentioned workarounds applies for me.

I tried all mentioned workarounds including:

- clearing the complete cache
- navigating to stackoverflow.com/users/login without further query strings

This [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306825/cannot-login-with-microsoft-edge-windows-10-browser#comment335338_306825) also mentioned that the only difference between his other devices and his pc is the fact that he doesn't use a Microsoft login for his pc. I use a domain account for my pc, but this is coupled with a Microsoft login.

Hopefully somebody can help me. Not being able to login to stackoverflow prevents me from using edge as my default browser.

**Edit**

This is the output on the network tab of the browser. There is a lot more, but that are only gets for pictures, ads, etc.
[image: NetworkTraffic]

What stands out, not sure what it means, but I see an error in the console tab:
[image]

Comment: Can you capture the network traffic, with the browser or a tool like Wireshark?

Comment: @Stijn See my edit for the output.

Comment: This is soo stressing. No idea on what is causing this behavior. I would really appreciate if someone from SO dev team looks at this  problem

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce it so far. My system is not joined to a domain, but I do log in with a Microsoft account. @Steve if you have any additional info to share, it might speed up the fixing process.

Comment: As explained in the other question I have been able to login first going to the login page, inserting the credentials and after the confirm going to the signup page. This shows the info about my account and allows to interact as a signed on user on the main site. Also opening my user account page works and allows to go everywhere as a signed in user.

Comment: But not everything starts to work. For example I cannot go, as a registered user, to the meta site. I cannot right click on the comments popup menu and go to the comment's page as a registered user, the same happens right clicking on the reputation popup and trying to go to an upvoted answer. Finally I don't think that is linked to the registered microsoft account because, since then, I have joined the work computer to a new microsoft account but the behavior doesn't change. And yes disabling flash player doesn't change anything

Comment: Is there any progress on this issue?

Comment: Nope, I was hoping that after the site JQuery update something would change and now I have noticed that albeit in my work PC I have flagged to clear cache and passwords everytime I close Edge, nevertheless, when I reopen Edge I can click on the SignUp button and voila, I am logged in. But the behavior for all other points is still the same.

Comment: @Steve, it is beginning to annoy me that it does not work. Is it maybe possible due to the redirection from https to http after the login. The console error I get has been resolved by going over SSL completely according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527387/script7002-xmlhttprequest-network-error-0x2ef3-could-not-complete-the-operati/19256487)

Comment: I think that this mess could be solved only if a dev from the SO team looks at this problem **and** he is able to reproduce it.